# Time function of Laplace tranform $F(s) = \frac{1}{s^2-1}$

Tags: laplace-transform

I have the following question:
*What are the time functions corresponding to the Laplace transforms below? What values will the time functions approach as time goes to infinity?*

$$F(s) = \frac{1}{s^2-1}$$

I assumed it was a standard Laplace transformed and wrote $\sinh(t)$, which is unbounded when $\lim_{t\to \infty} \sinh(t) = \infty$

But the expected answer is $f(t) = −0.5e^{−t} + 0.5e^t$, why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Exponential_definitions) for the definition of $\sinh(t)$ :$$\sinh(t) = −0.5e^{−t} + 0.5e^t$$

Answer (score 2):

It's just the definition of the Hyperbolic Sine:

$$\sinh(x) = \dfrac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2}$$

Whence your result.

As you can see

$$\lim_{t\to +\infty} \sinh(t) = \lim_{t\to +\infty} \dfrac{e^t - e^{-t}}{2} \to +\infty$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I should have looked up that! You both replied at the same time, which reply shall i accept?

Comment: @Dovendyr The one you like the most, or the more useful one. Your free choice!

Comment: @Dovendyr Please accept DMcMor's one. He has less points than me :)

Comment: I admit I really like your thoughtful answer but you have so elegantly asked to accept DMcMor's one so I did!